# How to open Java classes in a pop up JFrame window

Tags: java, string, user-interface, jframe

I am only beginning to learn Java. I have made a program that reads the user's email address that they enter and outputs the domain of that email.

Example: john@email.com ----> email.com

How can I launch this program on a JFrame user interface or a pop up window?

Comment: Please read a tutorial on basic GUI coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a popup box, you can use `JOptionPane`

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This appears in my popup box!", "My Popup Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```